# iOS: Sencha Touch Application and iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, extjs, sencha-touch

We have been developing an application which can consume a large amount of data (say tables/proxys with 4000 + rows) in Sencha Touch.

When we run the application on our desk top computer it works fine however when the application is accessed on an iPad as soon as we get to the data heavy task safari just vaporizes .

Is this a limitation on imposed by Apple or are we getting punished for doing something wrong.

Comment: Nope, you just discovered that an iPad has no 8Gb of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Try to load data as user request it:

http://podlipensky.com/post/2011/01/03/Sencha-Load-data-on-demand.aspx

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?120083-Ext.ux.touch.LazyDataView

Also try to use lazy rendering for not-visible-from-start elements. You need to use xtype and json configuration instead of creating new instance of control.